# How to preserve SELinux context on a file while running from unconfined user

Tags: linux, selinux, openstack-swift

I am having some trouble with a couple of my files' SELinux context with my openstack-swift setup

**Setup details:**

A daemon is running swift-object-replicator with following SELinux context

`system_u:system_r:swift_t:s0  swift ... /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/swift-object-replicator /etc/swift/object-server.conf`

This daemon calls a script periodically. The file created by that script has the following SELinux context

`system_u:object_r:swift_var_cache_t:s0 /var/cache/swift/object.recon`

Which is correct !!

**The issue**

If I run the same script(which that daemon is calling internally) from a terminal as 'root', the object.recon file SELinux context is modified as below `-rw-------. swift swift unconfined_u:object_r:var_t:s0   /var/cache/swift/object.recon`

And then I start seeing error messages in that daemon's log files

Any idea why the context changes and how to preserve it even if I wish to trigger the script from a terminal

Comment: You can't prevent it. SElinux is meant to do that. On the other hand, try creating a target policy for it.

Comment: @alvits Yes, that's what I was thinking. What kind of policy would that be ? Can you please give me the details

Comment: Here's [something to get you started](http://www.billauer.co.il/selinux-policy-module-howto.html).

Comment: We have a policy rule of the type `/var/cache/swift(/.*)?                             regular file       system_u:object_r:swift_var_cache_t:s0` but how to enforce it. Restorecon fixes things but only temporarily till someone again hits the command from terminal :(

Comment: Is SElinux enforcing or permissive?

Comment: The mode is Enforcing

Comment: Can you run this command `sesearch --allow --source swift_t --target swift_var_cache_t --class file` and update your post with the result?

Comment: It says `allow swift_t swift_var_cache_t : file { ioctl read write create getattr setattr lock append unlink link rename open } ;`

Comment: I had some luck with runcon command `runcon -t swift_t -r system_r -u system_u swift-object-replicator /etc/swift/object-server.conf -ov` This preserves the contexts

Comment: @alvits I am exploring type_transition rules now

Comment: This seems to have helped `module junk1 1.0;

require {
  type unconfined_t;
  type swift_exec_t;
  type swift_t;
  role unconfined_r;
  class process transition;
}

#============= TRANSITIONS ========
type_transition unconfined_t swift_exec_t:process swift_t;

#============= ROLES ==============
role unconfined_r types swift_t;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out 2 ways to retain the contexts:

- Use runcon to run the command with correct context

  ```
  runcon -t swift_t -r system_r swift-object-replicator /etc/swift/object-server.conf -ov
  ```
- Or, define a SELinux type_transition rule so that user with unconfined_t domain while executing the script transitions to the correct domain

  ```
  require {
   type unconfined_t;
   type swift_exec_t;
   type swift_t;
   role unconfined_r;
   class process transition;
  }

  role unconfined_r types swift_t;

  type_transition unconfined_t swift_exec_t:process swift_t;
  ```